# How do I write a short C program that accepts words and prints them?

Tags: c

I wrote the below code but I keep getting a "Command terminated by signal 11".

```
#include<stdio.h>
    
int main() 
{
    char *goodnight_message[20];
    printf ("Enter the goodnight message.\n");
    scanf ("%s", &goodnight_message);
    printf ("%s Buddy.\n", *goodnight_message);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tip: enable warnings when compiling your C programs (with the `-Wall -Wextra` flags if you are using gcc/clang).

Comment: What do you think `goodnight_message` and `&goodnight_message` are? There seems to be a misunderstanding of what a `char` array is and how should be used.

Comment: Ndaru John, are you looking to read a _line_ of user input or just 1 word or what?

Comment: 1 - Do you want to read separated words or sentences?
2 - Do you want to read only once or several words/sentences?

Comment: Note that you have 20 `char` pointers. Did you mean to simply declare an array of `char`, like `char goodnight_message[20];` and then do `scanf("%19s", goodnight_message);` and `printf("%s Buddy.\n", goodnight_message);`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There seems like you have a misconception of array and pointers..
While using array-like `goodnight_message[20]`;
The correct way to address its address is to use `&goodnight_message[0]` indicating the beginning of the array or to use `goodnight_message` simply. Both of these point to the 0th index of the array..

```
#include<stdio.h>
    
int main() 
{
    char *goodnight_message[20];
    printf ("Enter the goodnight message.\n");
    scanf ("%s", goodnight_message);
    printf ("%s Buddy.\n", goodnight_message);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Tip: You should use `gets(goodnight_message)` instead of `scanf` when you want a string that includes a space. You can also do this by using `scanf("%[^\n]s",goodnight_message);`, like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    char *goodnight_message[20];
    printf ("Enter the goodnight message.\n");
    scanf ("%[^\n]s", goodnight_message);
    printf ("%s Buddy.\n", goodnight_message);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A pro tip would be to never use `gets` which was removed in C11 for good reasons.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the extra s in `"%[^\n]s"` isn't actually part of the format specifier and should probably be removed.

Comment: as a beginner programmer, learning the "[^\n]" placeholder was very helpful.

Comment: @NdaruJohn Note that this answer misses a few parts (that I happened to mention in my answer). Running this code will also make your program have undefined behavior because it supplies `char**` to `scanf` and `printf` instead of `char*`.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you want *one* `char` array with 20 `char`s, not an array of 20 `char*` which is what you've got now.

Note that when passing arrays to functions, like `scanf` and `printf`, they decay into pointers to the first element. Also note that when using `scanf` to read strings, *always* set a maximum number of characters to read (one less than the size of the array to leave room for the null terminator). Otherwise the user may enter more characters and your program will write out of bounds.

You should also always check if `scanf` is successful by checking if it returns the same number of conversions you requested. You request one only, so check if it returns `1`.

A working program would then look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main()  {
    char goodnight_message[20];                   // now a char[] instead

    printf("Enter the goodnight message.\n");

    if(scanf("%19s", goodnight_message) == 1) {   // decays into a char*
        printf("%s Buddy.\n", goodnight_message); // decays into a char*
    }
}
```

This will however not read more than one word. To make `scanf` read until a newline you can add a set of characters to match in the conversion specifier with `[`*`characters`*`]`.

- If the first character of the set is `^`, then all characters **not** in the set are matched.

We want all characters except `\n` so lets add the set `[^\n]`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char goodnight_message[20];

    // an alternative to printf when you don't need formatting is puts:
    puts("Enter the goodnight message.");

    if(scanf("%19[^\n]", goodnight_message) == 1) {
        printf("%s Buddy.\n", goodnight_message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the extra `s` in `"%19[^\n]s"` isn't actually part of the format specifier and should probably be removed.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 Oups - indeed - corrected, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

line `char *goodnight_message[20];` creates an array of strings (array of char pointers)

to create single string use `char *goodnight_message;` or `char goodnight_message[20];`

warning: if you use `char *goodnight_message;`, you have to `malloc` it, so just stick to `[20]` for now

---

`scanf ("%s"` reads one string from input, but note that it is only to the next whitespace
for example, input `good night` would read only `good` and output `good buddy`
to read whole line use `gets(goodnight_message)` or `getline`

warning: `getline` is a bit complicated ([explanation](https://www.studymite.com/blog/strings-in-c#read_using_getline))

Comment: Please don't recommend the use of `gets`. It is deprecated as of C99 and removed as of C11 because it is susceptible to buffer overflows (`scanf("%s"` without max length in the specifier also suffers from a similar issue). Instead, you may want to use `fgets` which allows you to specify the max length. Also, `getline` is a POSIX-specific function so you may want to mention that.

Comment: `scanf("%19s", ...)` would be better

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 he is obviously a beginner, I didn't think he needs to complicate things

Comment: @Superior I suppose so, but better to learn what buffer overflows are and to avoid invoking undefined behavior earlier on IMO (especially in this case where the chance of this is higher due to OP's smaller buffer size). In any case, at least then consider recommending something like `scanf("%[^\n]")` because OP's compiler may very well be defaulting to C11 or higher, in which case `gets` won't even exist and then they'll be even more confused.